# Playframework generates logs/application.log under bin directory

Tags: playframework

I am using Play! 2.5.
After I packaged my project with `sbt dist`, every time I start the server by running the generated shell script, there will be an empty `application.log` under `some-path/bin/logs` directory, meanwhile the `some-path/logs/application.log` works as expected.
Could anyone tell me the reason? Thanks!

This is the `logback.xml` file:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel"/>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="application" level="DEBUG"/>

<!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
<logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF"/>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Currently I can solve that problem by changing the 
`<file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>`
to
`<file>logs/application.log</file>`
but I'm not sure if this is a good idea..

Comment: Share your logback configuration.

Comment: @marcospereira updated